# Undefined variable: required

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I try to make some reusable code for my laravel project.

I created one blade file call field.

*Note: this file will call every form page which i don't have to write same code over and over.*

```
<div class="form-group" id="{{ $name }}-group">
{!! Form::label($label) !!}
{!! Form::$type($name, null, [
    'class'                         => 'form-control',
    'required'                      => $required ? $required : 'required',
    'placeholder'                   => $label,
    'data-parsley-required-message' => $label.' is required',
    'data-parsley-trigger'          => 'change focusout',
    'data-parsley-pattern'          => $pattern ?  $pattern: '/^[a-zA-Z]*$/',
    'data-parsley-minlength'        => $minlength ? $minlength : '2',
    'data-parsley-maxlength'        => $maxlength ? $maxlength : '32',
    'data-parsley-class-handler'    => '#'.$name.'-group'
    ]) !!}
```

And in my form page i just call the field file like this.

*Note: There are some variable which i have set by default value in
field file, so whenever i need to change default value i just call the
variable inside.*

```
@include('backend.partials._Field', [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'name' => 'first_name',
                    'label' => 'First Name',
                ])
```

and i got error for Undefined variable: required. i know i can just call required varible in form page its will solve my problem but i want default data with the variable that i don't wanna call in form page.

anybody has any solution please.

Comment: Just change `$required ? $required : 'required'` to `isset($required) ? $required : 'required'` and it should work. You can also use [the null-coalesce operator](https://laravel-news.com/blade-templates-null-coalesce-operator) - `'required' => $required ?? 'required'`.

Answer (score 0):

Converting this to an answer...

Just change `$required ? $required : 'required'` to `isset($required) ? $required : 'required'` and it should work.

You can also use t[he null-coalesce operator](https://laravel-news.com/blade-templates-null-coalesce-operator) - `'required' => $required ?? 'required'`.